# PHP Use array (from earlier while loop) to query new foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to make a dynamic query using start/end date filters to display units per date. I already query which rows are available between the start and end date in the database and it creates an array like: `(array ("2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", 2020-03-03")`. When I want to use this array in another foreach to get the related units per day, I won't get any result. The big question is: What am I doing wrong?

The first while loop:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $date = $row["datetime"];

      $filterDates[] = '"'.$row["datetime"].'", ';
      }
}
```

When using this foreach I get results.

```
foreach (array("2020-03-10 00:00:00", "2020-03-11 00:00:00", "2020-03-12 00:00:00", "2020-03-13 00:00:00", "2020-03-14 00:00:00", ) as &$sqlDate)
```

When using this foreach I won't get results.

```
foreach (($filterDates) as &$sqlDate)
```

This is the 'dynamic' query I'm using to get the units per day

```
  $sql = "SELECT `datetime`, `period`, `units` , SUM(`Units`) AS 'units' FROM `Subscriptions_raw` WHERE `datetime` LIKE '%".$sqlDate."%' AND `period` = '1 Month' GROUP BY `datetime`";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

        echo $set[0]["units"].", ";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` on your `datetime`? What is that column's type? Also, why are you adding extra quotes here: `$filterDates[] = '"'.$row["datetime"].'", ';`?

Comment: It may be better to see if you can create 1 SQL statement to do this processing, this will help if you only do the first SQL to be able to run the second SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding dates in...

```
$filterDates[] = '"'.$row["datetime"].'", ';
```

You are adding a date something like...

```
"2020-03-10 00:00:00",
```

to the array, which will not match a date in the database (unlikely anyway).

You just need to add the date with no extra markup...

```
$filterDates[] = $row["datetime"];
```

Comment: That's it! I thought I had to markup the date to 'print' the correct markup. Thanks! I'll mark this as answer in a couple of minutes :-)